# How to generate a random number in the interval (0.8 ; 1)?

Tags: java, random, double

`Math.random()` gives a pseudorandom number on the interval (0 ; 1]. But I wanted to generate in other intervals, such as, (0.5 ; 0.6) or (0.7; 1] or (0.8 ; 1) etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble(0.5, 0.6));
    }
}
```

Comment: It is worth mentioning if result would be in range [0.5, 0.6), or (0.5, 0.6) or (0.5, 0.6] or [0.5, 0.6].

Answer (score 0):

You can "scale" the result of `Math.random` with multiplication, then "offset" it with addition. For example to map  [0 ... 1] to [0.5 ... 0.6[

```
float unit_scale(float n, float low, float high) {
    float scaled = n * (high - low);
    float offset = low + n;
    return offset;
}
```